# How to get all the files whose names contain certain pattern in the immediate subdirectory of the current directory without using find?

Tags: linux, bash

I try

```
ls */ | grep "\.txt$"
```

to find all .txt file in the subdirectory but it seems that it can't work well all the time.

Comment: what is the reason behind it not to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you want can easily be matched with a single glob:

```
ls */*.txt
```

The `ls` isn't necessary; it just demonstrates that it works. You can also use

```
echo */*.txt
printf '%s\n' */*.txt
files=( */*.txt )
for f in */*.txt; do ....
```

The pattern itself (`*/*.txt`) will expand to the list of the matching files; what you can *do* with that list is fairly broad.

Comment: For more complicated patterns, you can enable extended pattern matching (`shopt -s extglob`), which is just as powerful as regular expressions, but more efficient since you can match just the files you want, rather than matching a superset and filtering it after the fact.

Comment: Thanks very much! This is really helpful. Could you please explain what * and / mean in detail? I also want to know how to just print the file name without illustrating the path, thanks.